# 3d polygon in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, directx

Is there any way to draw a 3d polygon in xaml/directx using only point3d?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether you can bypass having a Camera, Light and stuff like this, I think the answer is no, sorry.

WPF cannot know how to draw a series of Point3D if it does not have this kind of information.